# FAQ display using Views

Tags: 7, views

I would like to set up a FAQ system using a custom content type and views. I would like to display the FAQs one of two common ways:

- Each question is a link that hides/displays the answer below it when the link is clicked, or
- Each question is a link that jumps down to a corresponding anchor on the page with the answer.

Are either of those possible in Views? I'm new to Drupal and learning as I go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module that will do exactly that, called [FAQ](http://drupal.org/project/faq).

And it also integrates with Views should you need to extend it. But out of the box, it should do the two things you need (I have used it and did both things).

Comment: Thanks! I need to dive into it, but it looks good for what I need.